# pyomo - variable optimization based on the independent variables value

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to optimize a routing problem and I am facing issue when I have to calculate the cost of shipment based on the volume being routed via Ship. I want to maximize the profit

```
profit = volume_sold * (selling_price - freight_cost)

Now the problem is freight cost is a function of volume.
E.g. If I volume_sold = 10mt the freight_cost = $10`

and if I volume_sold = 20mt the freight_cost = $20 and so on.
```

idea is to maximize the profit by selling different vol to diffrent customer who have different selling price and freight cost rate

```
    self.model.x_rpcy = pe.Var(self.model.R, self.model.P, self.model.C, self.model.Y,
                                   within=pe.NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=0)
    # defining the objective of the model. To maximise the variable i.e "model.contracted_amount"
        self.model.obj_quantity = pe.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=pe.maximize)
            def obj_rule(model):
            """
                calculates the objective of the model
                max_xz = Σr∈R,p∈P,c∈C,y∈Y (x_rpcy * (cp_ycp - s_cy -frieght cost-inladn cost

            :param model:
            :return:
            """
            sum_res = sum(
                model.x_rpcy[r, p, c, y] *
                (
                        get_contracted_price(y, c)
                         - get_freight_cost(c, model.x_rpcy[r, p, c, y])
                )
                for r in model.R for p in model.P for c in model.C for y in model.Y)
            return sum_res



            def get_freight_cost(p, vol):
            
                # in case vol has a very small value for which don't have a vessel size
                if pe.value(vol) < self.tolerance:
                    vol = 0

                # first figure out what is the volume we are trying to sell to this customer
                # based on the volume for a given customer and weight this is the cost
                if pe.value(vol) in vol_dict:
                    return vol_dict[pe.value(vol)]
            
                # big value of freight cost will reduce the final profit hence solver will exclude this C, Vol pair
                return 999999
```

If I remove the `- get_freight_cost(c, model.x_rpcy[r, p, c, y])` I get the expected output only based on selling price. I.e. customer with higher Selling price is being preferred however when I include the cost into the equation, i get even distribution for all. The model somehow ignores the cost function.

Could someone please help?

Comment: You probably need to implement a proper piecewise linear formulation. Doing this as a nonlinear function is usually not  (or rather: never) the right approach.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen could you please elaborate or give an example? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have an example that I can share. However, I have been involved in different procurement-type of models, and discounting/shipping cost was always formulated in a piecewise linear fashion such that linear solvers could be used. I have never seen anyone use the approach you are suggesting in your post.